# Designing a simple file manager

Tags: java, file, oop

I've been trying to come up with the best way to design my file manager for a project. I need to work with many file implementations and I have a File class made of 2 objects inside: Data and Descriptor.

[image: Here's my class diagram so far.]

As you can see, I have many different implementations of the Data class, one for each file organization. All of the implementations use records to organize their information but the fields for each kind of file (users, transactions, etc...) have to be stored as metadata inside their respective descriptor file. So basically my problem is trying to access and updating the descriptor of each file.

For example, while trying to search() inside the Users file from the Stacked class, I need the fields (username, name, last name, etc...) which are inside the Users Descriptor file, but I cant come up with a nice design for it. The only way I can think of is passing the Descriptor reference to each method (search, write, etc...) but I have a feeling that my solution would be bad design.

Please note that I still have to keep adding more file organizations for different files, so I want to plan ahead and have a nice file manager to handle all the requests the best way possible, but currently this is what I've come up with.

Comment: Maybe you should pass the reference to `Descriptor` to the `Data` constructor, and then use it internally?

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass a reference to Descriptors in each read()/search()? read() and search() are methods of FILE class, and Descriptor is a member of FILE, so read() and search() methods can refer Descriptor without any pssed information.

Comment: I'd like to see what classes and interfaces you have worked out so far.  That diagram is ok but I'm having a hard time visualizing this.  Honestly, problems like this are usually separate classes with no hierarchy between them.  They seem related, but they're not really.  Maybe just try making separate classes.

Comment: What exactly is search supposed to do?

Comment: @Soana It searchs for a record inside the file according to a value and a given key. Search, write, delete, etc.. all are operations applied to the file on their records.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion **["Cross-posting is frowned upon..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**

Comment: Thanks @gnat, deleted my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you shouldn't do it like you do it

One major goal of good object oriented design, is to keep the methods close to the data they use. This leads to *high [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)* and *low [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)*.

You in turn want to do the opposite. You want the data to be stored in different classes than the methods that use these data. This leads to a Code Smell called [Feature Envy](https://waog.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/code-smell-feature-envy/) and your `Description` is only a dumb [data class](http://waog.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/code-smell-data-class/).

I would strongly discourage you from keeping the separation, because it has no benefit in it's current form. Description is only a dumb

### How to do it better

A better solution would be, to merge `Description` into your `Data` class. This way every class has easy access to the data it needs.

### How to enforce your class seperation

If you want to enforce the separation of `Description` and `Data` anyway, you can use one of these solutions:

- add an association form `Data` to `Description` or
- use a [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)

---

**PS:** your compositions point into the wrong direction. Currently your data objects contain files and your descriptor objects contain other files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so by merging ``Descriptor`` into ``Data``, I also get rid of the ``File`` class right? And also for each implementation of the ``Data`` class, I need different object types, each representing a different "kind" of file (users, transactions). What would be a good design pattern for object types without creating a different class for each file? Thanks for your help, I'm trying to improve my programming design and this answers help a lot.

Comment: Keeping the file class is a matter of taste. But currently it looks like a Middle Man, which only delegates everything to data. So I also would get rid of it, yes. The question about the different file types is hard to answer, because important details are missing. What is a record exactly? what makes a user record different from a transactions record? etc. Maybe you can ask a second questions and post a link here in the comments, then I'll help you there.

Comment: PS: is it neccessary to do all that object serialization stuff on your own? if you're not doing some fundamental research, then try to find some persistence-library for your language, which stores whole objects for you. So you would just store a user object, and wouldn't bother about how it is stored or loaded.

Comment: Yeah its for a class so I have serialize everything on my own, cause I have to make the algorithms for each file organization. Thanks for all he help!